# How can I reorganize and separate data in a dataframe without knowing the column names?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make an app that allows a user to input a number of tickers and then run a series of analyses on them.

I have code that I wrote prior with a hard-coded list of tickers, but I wanted to be able to take a user's input using this:

```
tickers = []

tickers.append(input("Enter your first stock ticker (as it appears on the exchange (example: BBBY)) "))
tickers.append(input("Enter your second stock ticker."))
tickers.append(input("Enter your third stock ticker."))
tickers.append(input("Enter your fourth stock ticker."))
tickers.append(input("Enter your fifth stock ticker."))
print(tickers)
```

Then make an API call with those selected tickers and separate it the way this is done (SPY and AGG were the examples I had hard-coded prior):

```
stock_bond = alpaca.get_bars(
    tickers,
    timeframe,
    start = start_date,
    end = end_date
).df

SPY = stock_bond[stock_bond['symbol']=='SPY'].drop('symbol', axis=1)
AGG = stock_bond[stock_bond['symbol']=='AGG'].drop('symbol', axis=1)

stock_bond_df = pd.concat([SPY, AGG], axis=1, keys=["SPY", "AGG"])

stock_bond_df.head()
```

I'm not sure how to separate and organize this data without knowing which tickers the user selects.  Is there a way to organize the data by tickers with a random, unknown set of inputs?  Such as using a variable that stores the inputs, allowing the above code to still be viable?  Is there a better/more efficient way to do this?

I'm using Jupyter Notebook.  I'm also a beginner, so any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the sample data and the desired data in your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand,you are looking for a more dynamic way to filter dataframes based on a given set of user input symbols. I think you are going in the right direction by storing the user inputs in a list `tickers`.

You can simply then slice the dataframe based on this given list of tickers with `stock_bond[stock_bond['symbol'].isin(tickers)].drop('symbol', axis=1)`. Hope this is what you are looking for and I understood the question correctly.